# Resizing a background image via CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this background image that is 175x175 but I am trying to make a "CD" cover out of it. In the code below ([jsFiddle available](http://jsfiddle.net/weka/5CDnw/2/)), you will see it is not resized but merely "cropped". How do I fix this?

HTML:

```
<div class="cd"><div class="hole"></div></div>
<p>I want the image above to be resized to 75x75... but it's not</p>

<img src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/23679395.jpg" alt="Test" />
<p>Actual image size above.</p>
```

CSS:

```
.cd {
    -moz-border-radius: 63px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 63px;
    border-radius: 63px;
    background-image: url('http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/23679395.jpg');
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid #A1A1A1;
}
.cd .hole {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border:1px solid #A1A1A1;
    left: 28px;
    top: 28px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Please do some research first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size

Comment: I already got my answer -- thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) CSS property:

```
background-size: 75px 75px;
```

Alternatively:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

There's also the shorthand *[background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background)* property:

```
background: url('http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/23679395.jpg') 100% 100%;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use background-size like here:

```
.cd {
    -moz-border-radius: 63px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 63px;
    border-radius: 63px;
    background-image: url('http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/23679395.jpg');
    background-size: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid #A1A1A1;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5CDnw/6/

Answer (score 1):

Use background-size:cover it will fill the container whatever will be the size of container.

```
.cd {
    -moz-border-radius: 63px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 63px;
    border-radius: 63px;
    background-image: url('http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/23679395.jpg');
    background-size:cover;/*Add This*/
    -webkit-background-size: cover;/*Add This for webkit*/
    -moz-background-size: cover;/*Add This for mozilla*/
    -o-background-size: cover;/*Add This for opera*/
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid #A1A1A1;
}
```

Comment: +1 here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CDnw/8/) I was about to post as an answer.